# GraphDB Workbench would not start

Tags: graphdb

After a VM shutdown, GraphDB Workbench would not start.

I have installed GraphDB on a cloud-hosted VM. Incidentally, the machine was shut down without stopping GraphDB. When trying to start it again, the Workbench would not start and the following message is displayed in the error log.

> [ERROR] 2019-06-19 12:12:00,299 [Thread-10 | c.o.t.s.i.PluginManager]
>   Problem shutting down literals-index java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.ontotext.trree.transactions.TransactionException: Failed to
>   created journal file: /home/peio/graphdb-se-8.10.1/data/repositor
>   ies/bgnews/storage/literals-index/numerics.index.precommit

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace in the logs? If so, could you send it to `graphdb-support` for further investigation?
Other than that, you could manually delete the 'literals-index' folder located in `/home/peio/graphdb-se-8.10.1/data/repositor ies/bgnews/storage` and restart GraphDB. That will recreate the literal index on repository initialization.

Answer (score 0):

As Damyan suggested, delete literals-index in the storage folder and it will be rebuilt on start-up.